# Glsl phong shader and camera

Tags: opengl, camera, glsl, lighting

I know this question was asked a lot already, but I still can't manage to do it right.

So, in my vertex shader I need to get light postition and eye position. Here is my code:

```
void main(void)
{
    vec3    p = vec3      ( gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex );

    l = normalize (vec3 (gl_LightSource[0].position));
    v = normalize ( vec3 ( eyePos )  - p );
    n = normalize ( gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal );

    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

As the result light moves with the movement of camera. What exactly do I need to do here? Possibly without use of non-opengl matrices.

Is there an example of glsl lighting with proper camera control?

*** UPDATE ***

Thanks to Kos, i managed "lights move with camera" problem, but here is another one:

I have

```
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
ctLight -> enable();

glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);
    glutSolidTeapot(2.0);
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 8);
    glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);
    glutSolidTeapot(2.0);
glPopMatrix();

ctLight -> disable();
glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);
```

Now the second teapot lights the same as one in (0, 0, 0). How do i fix this?

Vertex shader code in case:

```
void main(void)
{
    vec3    p = vec3 ( gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex );            // transformed point to world space

    l = normalize ( vec3 (gl_LightSource[0].position) );
    v = normalize ( - p );  

    h = normalize ( l + v );
    n = normalize ( gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal );                  // transformed n

    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't remember much about "old" lighting features in OpenGL, but I believe that your problem is having an invalid value in `gl_LightSource[0].position`.

How do you specify the light position (`glLightParameterfv(GL_LIGHT_POSITION, ...);`)? Most importantly, what's the state of the model-view matrix when you specify them?

If the model-view matrix is identity, you specify the light positions in **eye space**, which gives you the impression that they move with the camera (well, remember that the camera is at (0,0,0) always and it's the world which moves).

For a correct result, I believe you should specify the lights in **world space**, i.e. after performing camera transformations on the model-view matrix, but before doing any other operations on it.

The light position is multiplied by the model-view matrix at the moment of specification, so **your shader will always get the value in eye space**, which is useful - you don't need to modify it any more since lighting calculations are done in eye space. This also implies that `eyePos` should be just `(0,0,0)` in your calculations, which makes `v` equal to just `normalize(-p)`.

Also, for best results make those calculations in fragment shader, not vertex shader. :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: what i did: 1. moved "glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);" right after render() function, which sets up modelview matrix with gluLookAt. 2. changed v to normalize(p), as you adviced. now the back side of my teapot looks dark as it should, but if I look around on light side the glare spot still moves. should it? I am not sure

Comment: If the "glare spot" is the specular highlight, then yes. Ambient component is always the same, diffuse component depends on surface-light vector (and it should not change when you move your camera), and specular component also takes surface-eye vector into consideration.

Comment: What do you mean "lights the same"? How it's supposed to be lit, and how it is? Also, how do you specify the light position? Is it a point light or directional light?

Comment: for example if i have 4 boxes flying around my light, then every box lights as if light placed from the right. and in my light i use lightPos[4] = { 3.0,  4.0, 0.0, 0.0 };